# Wicket return class from getHomePage is loaded before session create

Tags: session, jetty, wicket

I am using wicket 1.5.8 on jetty server,
and in my getHomePage() return class (let's call it class A) I am using the session that is been created in newSession function , the problem is that in class A when I call Session.get().getId() I get null, when I checked the issue I saw that the session is been create after my A class is loaded. 
does any one now how to make the session load before the return class from getHomePage()

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your session is still temporary, call Session#bind().